# Get httpservletrequest in doFilter without type casting from ServletRequest

Tags: java, servlets, httprequest, servlet-filters, multipart

I introduced filter in my application for a validation. When I invoke doFilter method,

```
public void doFilter (ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse,FilterChain filterChain)
```

I can't use `getParts()` in `doFilter()`. `getParts()` is available in `HttpServletRequest`.

Even though I type cast from `ServletRequest` to `HttpServletRequest`, I am getting null value.

Question is,is there any way to access `HttpServletRequest` inside `doFilter()` without type cast from `ServletRequest`? Or how can I directly access `HttpServletRequest` inside `doFilter()` without passing it into the method?

Below snippet I get error

```
for(final Part part : ((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest).getParts())
```

Comment: What servlet container do you use? Tomcat? Which version?

Comment: I am using Tomcat 7.

Comment: How would not having to typecast solve the problem? The typecast succeeded, so that wasn't the problem, so there's no reason to want to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

In Tomcat this is a known but solved problem. See this bug report: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49711

There is now an option (`allowCasualMultipartParsing`) to configure Tomcat to allow `getParts()` calls is servlet filters (default is off). See the [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html):

> `allowCasualMultipartParsing`:
>   Set to true if Tomcat should automatically parse multipart/form-data request bodies when HttpServletRequest.getPart* or HttpServletRequest.getParameter* is called, even when the target servlet isn't marked with the @MultipartConfig annotation (See Servlet Specification 3.0, Section 3.2 for details). Note that any setting other than false causes Tomcat to behave in a way that is not technically spec-compliant. The default is false